# solving initial value problem and finding interval of validity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$(t^2 - 14 t + 24 ) \frac { dy }{ dt } = y, \quad y(7)=1$$
>
> a) solve with $y$ as a function of $t$
>
> b) on what interval is the solution valid
>
> c) find the limits of the solution as $t$ approaches the left and right ends of the interval

So, when I tried the equation, I got this monstrosity:
$$y=\frac{C(x-12)^{1/10}(x-2)^{9/10}}{x-2}.$$
Issue is when I try finding the specific solution with $y(7)=1$, since plugging in $x$ as $7$ would put a negative under the tenth root

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Hint*: The general solution should be $y^{10}=C(t-2)/(t-12)$ or absorbing the minus sign and the tenth-root into $C$, $y=C((t-2)/(t-12))^{1/10}$.